# Select object only if it have different element from previous one with jq

Tags: bash, jq

The goal is to print the object only if a value of it is different from the previous object.

Imagine this json:

```
[
   {
      "date": "10-03-20",
      "value": 3
   },   
   {
      "date": "11-03-20",
      "value": 3
   },   
   {
      "date": "12-03-20",
      "value": 3
   },   
   {
      "date": "13-03-20",
      "value": 8
   },   
   {
      "date": "14-03-20",
      "value": 8
   },   
   {
      "date": "15-03-20",
      "value": 5
   }
]
```

The expected output should be:

```
[
   {
      "date": "10-03-20",
      "value": 3
   }, 
   {
      "date": "13-03-20",
      "value": 8
   },  
   {
      "date": "15-03-20",
      "value": 5
   }
]
```

Only print object if `value` is different of the previous object.

This what I start to do with jq:

```
[foreach .[] as $row (null;
    select($row.value != $lastValue) | $row.value
    $lastValue = $row.value
    )]
```

Of course this doesn't work, I can't use variable with jq like this, i don't know if this is the good way to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `reduce` here is probably easier than using `foreach`:

```
reduce .[] as $x (null;
    if . == null then [$x]
    elif .[-1].value == $x.value then .
    else . + [$x] end)
```

#### Solution using `foreach`

For reference, here's a solution using `foreach`.  The key idea is to use foreach's state variable to store the "local variables" that you might use in a different language.

```
[ foreach .[] as $x ({};
    if .prev == $x.value then .emit = null
    else {prev: $x.value, emit: $x}
    end;
    select(.emit).emit ) ]
```